# Feature Image on Wordpress 6.0.1 says it’s too small

Tags: wordpress

Here’s an issue that I wonder if other Wordpress users are struggling with ever since the latest update 6.0.1.

I’ve a client that used to upload feature images as he saw fit taking in account the weight of the file and not letting the images be too small but I think it was since we’ve updated Wordpress this week that he started to see a message:

```
The featured image should have a size of at least 1200 by 675 pixels.
```

It’s okay, when it happened we just had to make the image bigger but I’m wondering if this message started to show with this update or if it would already show up before we had updated, if we had uploaded any feature image below this measures. Because it’s kind of strange it never showed before.

Comment: The codebase makes no mention of this. Are you sure this is not caused by a theme or plugin?

Comment: It could only be theme or Wordpress itself but to be the theme it would be weird that we never got this message before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often this is due to an issue with an AMP plugin.  Confirm that any AMP plugins you have installed are functioning correctly.

Comment: Well it happened that the theme AMP plugin was activated without some of us being aware and after a couple of problems it was actually disabled and the message disappeared while we were still figuring it out. 
Our theme support said that it was due to some Wordpress update, but we haven’t seen it showing up since we made sure AMP was disabled. I didn’t knew this could actually have been the reason to solve this o.o